# need to replace a value in the string with the value that's reading explicitly

Tags: java, string

How can we replace  a value that is highlighted below with the one that is to be read explicitly?

```
String msg ="BGM+EFD:20:109:GBP+aa:bb:cc+5+dd'CST++KindOfDeclaration+0'";
```

i.e I need to read a value from a server. It is reading it correctly but it is also replacing the previous value 109.

For example if the value it is reading is 56, it replaces 109 as 1056 which I don’t need. I have given the code as below

```
String msg ="BGM+EFD:20:109:GBP+aa:bb:cc+5+dd'CST++KindOfDeclaration+0'";
String bgm=msg.split("\\'") [0];

String tempMessage=bgm;

String messageFunction="56";

System.out.println(bgm);

if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(messageFunction)){

    bgm=bgm.replace(bgm.split("\\+")[3],messageFunction);
}
else{
    bgm=bgm.replace(bgm.split("\\+")[3],"9");
}
msg=msg.replace(tempMessage, bgm);
```

Required output is

```
BGM+EFD:20:109:GBP+aa:bb:cc+56+dd'CST++KindOfDeclaration+0'";
```

But I’m getting the output as

```
BGM+EFD:20:1056:GBP+aa:bb:cc+56+dd'CST++KindOfDeclaration+0'";
```

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] of what you want. This is unclear. You logic don't make much sense. Also, you should check Regex for that kind of job. Not that my output look like : `BGM+EFD:20:109:GBP+aa:bb:cc+56+dd'CST++KindOfDeclaration+0'` so what have you tried ?

Comment: Provided code is working fine. You can see an example [here](https://ideone.com/ZRpj46). _Since `StringUtils` is not in java SE, so it is not used in example_. You can also check it offline in your IDE. Problem seems in any other part of your code.

Comment: why not `msg.replace("5", "56")`

Answer (score 0):

As your actual code is working (the output I get is not the incorrect one you post), here is an other solution with regex:

Here is a simple regex to do almost the same conversion

```
msg = msg.replaceAll(
     "(.*\\+)(\\d+)(\\+.*'.*)", 
     "$1"
          + (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(messageFunction) ? messageFunction : "9" ) 
          + "$3"
)
```

This regex `"(.*\\+)(\\d+)(\\+.*'.*)"` just let me get the last value between "+ +" before a `'` in a specific group. This could be improved I guess. But the result is correct.

```
group 1 : (.*\\+)
group 2 : (\\d+) the value you seek
group 3 : (\\+.*'.*)
```

I am not a master in regex, so it is probably not 100% safe but this still can be improved.